# Best way to find matched record using two Data frames in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Actually I am writing a script to find matched records using df1 and df2.
Now I am doing this by iterating both df1 and df2 in O N^2.

```
for i,row1 in df1.iterrows:

   for j,row2 in df2.iterrows:

      if row1['fname'] == row2['fname'] 
        and row1['lname'] == row2['lname'] 
        and row1['email'] == row2['email']:
        #matched
```

I want to make it in more efficient way. Anyone can guide me which algorithm or Python thing I can use for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `merge`.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=(['fname','lname','email']), how='inner')
```

Comment: @U.Malik `merge` command joins both dataframes `df1` and `df2` on 3 columns `fname,lname,email` using `inner join`. This will basically return only those records which are present in both dataframes. Let me know if need further explanation.